# Erdős Prime Sieve Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I think this is/was an Erdős conjecture. I can't find it, or see how to prove it.

> We know all primes but a finite number can be expressed as $6k\pm1$. If we have a finite set of moduli using $n>6$ and residues $\pm1$, can they cover all but a finite number of primes?
>
> For example,$\{8,10,12\}$ being $8\alpha\pm1, 10\beta\pm1, 12\gamma\pm1$, but $103$ isn't covered amongst an infinite number of others.

I think the answer is no. I tried using Dirichlet's arithmetic progression theorem, but I'm not sure this counts as a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent conjecture: there is some $N$ such that for every large enough $n$, $n\equiv\pm1\pmod k$ for some $6<k<N.$

Now let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of primes $p$ which are of the form $12m+5$ such that $2m+1$ and $3m+1$ are prime. If $p\in\mathcal{P}$ then $k\ge2m+1$. Hence if $\mathcal{P}$ is infinite (as is believed on standard conjectures, e.g., Schinzel's) then your conjecture fails.

Comment: where do you get (12,5), (2,1) and (3,1) from?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: It's just a way to ensure that $p\pm1$ have no small prime factors except 2 and 3. Many other choices are possible.